# Good tutorial for my first Custom Service Application in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, service-application

I found [this one](http://sharepointegg.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-custom-service-application-in.html), but it has a step that says to "Select the “WCF Service” project template...", which wouldn't make sense for adding a New Item (at least that doesn't sound right to me).

I'm curious if anyone can recommend a good beginners tutorial for writing your first Custom Service Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193964.aspx

It's long and painful but is still the best one i've found so far.  Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but still.. Have a look at:

https://serviceappstarterkit.codeplex.com/

Pretty straightforward to get the helloworld example working

Answer (score 1):

Video @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg620670

[One More](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/en-us/office/media/video/sharepoint.html?cid=sharepoint-video&VideoID=3880ebb0-b932-4631-a54a-22982f8af38d&from=mscomoffice)